# REST API - Retrieve all the resources a user have an access to

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

How can I get a list of all resources, a user has access to using REST API? Because sometimes a user can have limited access to just a few files and document library in a SharePoint Site. So, I want to use SharePoint REST API to get details (like resource name and URL) of all the individual resources a user has access to. Can anyone please help me with that?

I tried

```
{{site-url}}/_api/web/siteusers?$filter=Email eq 'some mail id'
```

But the above endpoint is not showing the list of resources a user has access.